# Why don't we use vector sign for quantities in 1D motion?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, velocity, notation

My school textbook says that we don't need to use unit vectors (**i** ,**j**,**k**) to represent the direction of vectors in 1D motion as + and - sign indicate direction. But that is creating a lot of confusion like this:

Suppose a question for one dimensional motion is like this: a body is thrown vertically upwards with a speed of 10 m/s.
Here if we consider upward direction as positive, then I have seen information written like this:

v= + 10 m/s
a=-g=-9.8 m/s^2

But I don't agree with the way it is written. I am relating it with vectors. Firstly, why are they not using vector symbol when it has both magnitude and direction ( with + or - indicating direction). Secondly, a should represent the magnitude of acceleration vector but magnitude can't be negative. So why it is written like this?

Rather I think they should write like this:

**v**=+10 m/s

**a**=-9.8 m/s^2

Am I right?
Note: bold letters here represent the symbol of vectors.

Comment: The right sides of your vector equations need a $\mathbf{k}$. You can’t say a vector equals a scalar value (except for zero, which is shorthand for the zero vector).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In 1D why are vectors, such as, e.g., velocity $v$ and acceleration $a$, not written with a vector arrow?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363113/)

Comment: if you want to use vectors even in $1$D, you can. For example, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/542312/203278) of mine where I present an answer using vectors even in $1$D), but the thing is, you don't have to. Because once you specify a direction $\hat{\xi}$ which you call "positive", then every other vector can be written as $c \hat{\xi}$ for some $c \in \Bbb{R}$. This $c$ could be positive, negative or $0$, and depending on which it is, you'll know what the direction of the vector is. That's why once you specify a "positive" direction, all you need is $+-$.